# Can user-data be executed before EC2 instances are placed in WarmPool and stopped state?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can user-data be executed before EC2 instances are placed in WarmPool and stopped state?

I need EC2 instances to be initialized and execute User-data script before put into WarmPool and in warmed:stopped state but it seems like it just goes straight to warmed:stopped state without running the user-data.

Comment: No, you have to use lifecycle hooks instead of user-data https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/warm-pool-instance-lifecycle.html

Comment: Hi @MarkB I assume, I will have to use ssm doc or lambda to execute any script that I have on the user-data?